# solidity variables to store decentralized identities keys -- bytes32 sufficient for a ED25519 keys?

Tags: bytes32, erc725

I am building a next generation decentralized identity solution. Would like to under which solidity variable is best suited to store decentralized identities keys -- bytes32 sufficient for a ED25519 keys?

Thank you.

Nathan Aw

Comment: From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Ed25519, private keys and public keys are 256bits (32 bytes) and signatures are 512 bits (64 bytes).